# Link error as chain in celery

Tags: python, python-2.7, celery

I have a function where I kick off a sample job and update the database accordingly. My function is like this:

```
def schedule_sample_job(hosts):
       parent_job_id = 'SampleBatchJob|%s|Phantom' % uuid.uuid1()
       child_jobs = []
       host_entries = []
       for host in hosts:
           job_id = 'SampleJob|%s|Phantom' % uuid.uuid1()
           res = chain(
              add.si(2, 2),
              add.si(3, 3),
              throw_exception.si('4'),
              mul.si(4, 4),
              mul.si(5, 5)
           )
           capacity_task = res.apply_async(
               serializer='json',
               link=[change_job_status.s(job_id, 'SUCCESS')],
               link_error=[change_job_status.s(job_id, 'FAILED'), change_parent_job_status.s(parent_job_id)]
           )
           host_entry = {'host': host}
           host_entries.append(host_entry)
           celery_util = CeleryUtil()
           celery_util.store_chain_job(
               job_id,
               capacity_task,
               parent_job_id,
               'anonymous',
               [host_entry]
           )
           child_jobs.append(job_id)

      celery_util = CeleryUtil()
      celery_util.store_chain_job(parent_job_id, child_jobs, None, 'anonymous', host_entries)
      job_status = celery_util.build_job_status(parent_job_id)
      return job_status
```

As you can see I try to kick off a job for each host and have multiple tasks in the link_error, I want this to be like a chain, where one tasks executes AFTER the other one **finishes execution**. This doesn't happen that way in my program. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: While starting a worker you can specify concurrency as 1, so that only one job executes at a time.

Comment: Haha, looking for a solution, obviously, wouldn't want to set the concurrency to one as that limits my performance big time. Thanks for the suggestion though